# Compare a table with a count result from another table and add the names that have a zero count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am counting how many times a company has ordered. Then I am only showing if a company has ordered less than 5 times. I am then checking it against the table with all company names to see what company has not ordered, which would not show up on the order table, then add their name on the displayed list. 
What I have tried:

```
Select Orders.CustomerID, Count(Orders.CustomerID) AS OrderCount
    From Orders Left Join Customers
    On Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID 
    Group By Orders.CustomerID
    Having Count(Orders.CustomerID) <5
```

This is totally wrong:

```
Select CustomerID 
From Customers
Where EXISTS
    (Select CustomerID, Count(CustomerID) AS 'OrderCount'
    From Orders
    Group BY CustomerID
Having Count(Orders.CustomerID) < 5)
```

I need to somehow compare the list of names before I ask it to see which ones have ordered less than 5 times.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is tagged both [tag:mysql] (a cross-platform, open-source RDBMS, now owned by Oracle) and [tag:sql-server] (a proprietary, closed-source RDBMS from Microsoft).  Which are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `LEFT JOIN`, interchange the table names since you want to show values from `Customers`, otherwise use `RIGHT JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT  Customers.CustomerID, 
        COUNT(Orders.CustomerID) AS OrderCount 
FROM    Customers 
        LEFT JOIN Orders  
           ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID 
GROUP   BY Customers.CustomerID 
HAVING  COUNT(Orders.CustomerID) < 5
```

using `EXISTS()`

```
SELECT  CustomerID 
FROM    Customers c
WHERE   EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    Orders o
            WHERE   o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
            GROUP   BY CustomerID 
            HAVING  COUNT(CustomerID) < 5
        )
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not produce the correct results. It is missing the 2 customers that did not order at all. It only returned a null row as a customer name.

Comment: maybe you should see the updated answer and if possible add sample records.

Comment: The Left join worked, I noticed that I had an extra character in the wording and that through a wrench in it. What one little thing can do.

Comment: by the way, what server you are using? sql server or mysql?

Comment: SQL Server and Management studio

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName, COUNT(O.CustomerID) AS OrderCount 
FROM Customers C
LEFT JOIN Orders O ON O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID 
GROUP BY C.CustomerID 
HAVING OrderCount < 5
ORDER BY OrderCount, C.CustomerName
```

Comment: Please don't encourage to use alias on `HAVING` clause. It is not standard, it only works in mysql.